# Fundamental group of the Grothendieck ring scheme

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, kt.k-theory-and-homology, fields, grothendieck-rings

Let $K_0(V_k)$ be the Grothendieck ring of $k$-varieties with $k$ a field. Let **S$_k$** be its affine scheme. Is this a *connected* scheme for any field ? (I understand that this could be a very naive question, but I have not found an immediate answer yet.)

Is it known what the topological fundamental group $\pi_1($**S**$_k)$ is of (the connected components of) **S$_k$** ?

Comment: I think there are zero-divisors (by Borisov), so it is not irreducible over $\mathbb{C}$. Not sure about connectedness. What do you mean by topological fundamental group? It may make sense over topological fields; over $\mathbb{C}$, to apply GAGA you need your scheme to be separated and of finite type (I am not sure if your scheme satisfied second requirement); probably for rigid-analytic GAGA there are similar requirements. Maybe etale fundamental group would make more sense in this context.